# LINQ: Timeout by Time comparison within DbSet<Model>.Where()

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I try to query with EF core 2.2 and Linq a SQL database.

In the database, the time column `R00090` is of type `float`.

Using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`, I created the `DbContext` and model class. Everything works as it should except for the following problem.

Code snippet #1: work within 2 ms

```cs
var time = (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)).ToOADate(); 
var test = context.TbMlr21P07
                    .OrderByDescending(e => e.R00090)
                    .Where(e => e.R00090 > (time))
                    .ToList();
```

Code snippet #2: get timeout after 30 s

```cs
var test = context.TbMlr21P07
                    .OrderByDescending(e => e.R00090)
                    .Where(e => e.R00090 > ((DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)).ToOADate()))
                    .ToList();
```

I do not understand why the "time calculation" in the Linq expression runs into a timeout and when using a variable it does not? Should the "time calculation" not be evaluated as with the variable and then the query be created?

I think both code examples are the same in behavior, but snippet #2 throws a timeout exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'`
>
> Inner Exception:
>   Win32Exception: The wait process was aborted

(*Inner exception translated from German*)

Comment: `Where()` will do the date calculation for every item in your collection, storing the date in a variable will do it once.

Comment: Thank you,

So it is always better to buffer such comparison values beforehand in a variable?

Comment: Also be sure there are no hidden type conversions in the query.